# Google Guava compilation issue with Junit test

Tags: java, junit, guava

I am trying to adopt **com.google.guava version 21.0** into my  project to leverage some of powerful API offered by this API.

My setup as below:

```
<guava.version>21.0</guava.version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

I tried to use StopWatch class to measure the peformance of a test method as below:

```
 Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        testSearchForAbsa();
        testSearchForIntranet();
        testSearchForWealth();

        logger.info("Test All elapsed time: {}", stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        stopwatch.stop();
```

I got following exception:

```
C:\sourcecode\gis\tranganh_SGPDWMVDI037068_7418\tranganh_SGPDWMVDI037068_4204\depot\GIS\AIM\phoenix\_main.br\phoenix\ad-connector\src\test\java\com\phoenix\ad\connectors\impl\OIMClientAdConnectorTest.java
Error:(3, 30) java: package com.google.common.base does not exist
Error:(24, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Stopwatch
  location: class com.phoenix.ad.connectors.impl.OIMClientAdConnectorTest
Error:(24, 31) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Stopwatch
  location: class com.phoenix.ad.connectors.impl.OIMClientAdConnectorTest
```

I am not sure how it happening? anyone incountering this issue, please advise?

Comment: I am using `JAVA 8 (version 1.8.0_66)`

Answer (score 0):

that was problem with my IntelliJ IDE as I was able to compile and run throught Maven command, i got it resolved after restarting IDE.